# How to remove namspace from category view

Tags: mediawiki

My Mediawiki has many namespaces. When I click [[Category:MyCategory]], it prints a list of articles that belong to this "MyCategory" category. But they have "namespace:" on front of such article. Is any way: (1) use different color for "namespace", so this page will not look so ugly. Or, another option, to have multiple sections. Each section will have "Title" (namespace), and all articles in such sections will be shown without "namespace:".

Any suggestion how to tune PHP code of Mediawiki will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can style the namespace prefixes on category pages by creating a *gadget*, provided you have [the *MediaWiki* extension *Gadgets*](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Gadgets) enabled:

- in `MediaWiki:Gadgets-definition`, to create a gadget definition and make the new gadget turned on by default, add:

```
* grayNSinCategory[ResourceLoader|default]|grayNSinCategory.js|grayNSinCategory.css
```

- in `MediaWiki:Gadget-grayNSinCategory`, to create a human-readable title for the gadget to appear in personal settings:

```
Make namespace prefixes on category pages appear gray
```

- in `MediaWiki:Gadget-grayNSinCategory.js`, to wrap all namespace prefixes of the page titles on category pages:

```js
if ( mw.config.get ('wgNamespaceNumber') === 14 ) {
    // This is a category page.
    $(document).ready (function ($) {
        $('.mw-category-group>ul>li>a').html( function (_, text) {
            // Wrap the namespace prefix in a span with .ns class:
            return text.replace( /^.+?:/, '<span class="ns">$&</span>' );
        });
    });
}
```

- in `MediaWiki:Gadget-grayNSinCategory.css`, to make the namespace prefixes, now wrapped in `span`s with `.ns` class, appear of less saturated colours:

```css
.mw-category-group>ul>li>a>.ns {
    color: #8080C0;
}

.mw-category-group>ul>li>a:visited>.ns {
    color: #A080A0;
}
```

Do not forget to purge browser cache (Ctrl + F5).